# Delete a large chunk of lines from a huge file

Tags: text

I have a 2.8GB sql dump file in linux. I need to delete lines 18 through 3000, but I can't open it in a text editor like vim because it's so big.

Any suggestions? I assume you could use sed or something similar, I just don't know the command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that's what sed was designed for:

```
sed '18,3000d' input.txt > output.txt
```

**Resources**

- [Sed man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

Comment: I love sed! sed rocks!